# LUA Hooks - Command Modern Operations & PE

Tags: lua, modding

Looking for examples of utilizing the available LUA hooks for modding the games [Command: Modern Operations](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1076160/Command_Modern_Operations/) and the simulation suit [Command: Professional Edition](https://pro.matrixgames.com/game/command-professional-edition).

Comment: [Typing those keywords into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=lua+hook+command+modern+operations&ia=images) is turning up some [promising results](https://github.com/brianbob12/Command-Modern-Operations-Lua). What have you found or tried in your research thus far, and what specific aspect do you need help with? This site isn't a search engine to get links to existing examples, but we can write up tailored answers if you can detail a specific problem to solve.

Comment: I have the latest LUA instruction manuals but the references to utilizing hooks is pretty vague at least to me. just looking for someone that has utilized these 'hooks' to hopefully provide some reference guidance or coding examples.

Comment: Try editing your question to show what you've found about this in the documentation so far, and explain what specific aspects you need clarified.